# fatal error C1010 в Visual Studio - как правильно решить?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Мне прям неловко, что задаю такие вопросы. Есть "дерево":

```
(папка) MyProject
  stdafx.h
  myFile.cpp
  (папка) Qwerty
    qwe.cpp
```

В файле `myFile.cpp` я пишу `#include "stdafx.h"`, в файле `qwe.cpp` пишу `#include "..\stdafx.h"` и при компиляции возникает ошибка из заголовка. Однако, я нажал правой кнопкой мыши на файл `qwe.cpp` и там выбрал в свойствах `"Not Using Precompiled Headers"`, после чего ошибка исчезла. При том, что в файле `myFile.cpp` он в свойствах продолжает использоваться.
Это значит, что файл `stdafx.h` может использоваться только в том `.cpp` файле, где есть `main()`, правильно? То есть, мне вручную нужно будет отключать `"использовать.."` во всех `.cpp` файлах, которые я создам? Или как-то можно использовать `stdafx.h` во всех `.cpp` (как?)? И, если можно, то в этом вообще есть смысл? Или же достаточно одного `stdafx.h` в `.cpp` файле с `main()`?

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем вам этот stdafx.h

Comment: Насколько я понял, он ускоряет компиляцию. Плюс в него можно запихнуть все ` #include <>`, которые использую

Comment: Насчет ускорения не знаю :-) А если вам нужны все инклюды в одном месте - сделайте свой заголовок, вообще проблем не вижу, это распространенная практика :-)

Comment: так-то да, но, раз Visual Studio создает его, значит, он ей зачем-то нужен) судя по всему, этот файл нужно включать только в файл с исполняющей функцией `main()`

Comment: Если создавать пустой проект без Precompiled headers - не создает.